# How to get the LEN of a cell after a condition test

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I would like to know how to obtain the number of characters in a cell after a condition has been passed.

I know that LEN(cell) is used to obtain this. However I would like to be able to add this number up, for example;

```
  Time         Text

  5:00         text

  5:00         text

  5:01         text
```

Would result in the ONLY the two 5:00 rows having their text cells lengths added together.

I would expect the result of this test to result in the number 8 being returned.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post expected result for cells having 05:00 hour?

Comment: Are you looking only for excel formula? if so this would belong on superuser.com and you may get better answers there. if you are also OK with a VBA code, then edit the question and specify the same or add a tag

Comment: sorry never used super user, usually program Java and the like and this was just needed for a project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
          Col A    Col B     Col C
 1        05:00    aaa       
 2        05:01    bb   
 3        05:00    ccccc
```

In cell C1 add the following:

```
=SUM(IF(A1:A3=A1,LEN(B1:B3),FALSE)) //result = 8 (i.e aaa=3 and ccccc=5)
```

Please note:

1. This **must** be added as an array formula i.e. press `CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER`
2. In this instance I am checking for times equal to 05:00 (A1 in the formula). Please change as needed